# Enable show flag history for moderators on posts that don't have flags on them

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

In the moderator tools, we have an option to view the flag history of a post.  In this flag history, we can also see deletions and undeletions.  While you'll also see this on the post if you click on the link for the revisions, the link isn't visible unless there's an actual edit on the post.

Today, there was a flag raised by Community for "possible vandalism, posts deleted in short period of time".  I looked at the posts, and there was one with an edit history on it that had been deleted and then undeleted.  However, the four other posts didn't have any edit history (and therefore, no link to the revision history), but they *were* deleted and undeleted.

In order to get the flag history, I had to hack the URL for each post.  I shouldn't have to do this, I should be able to view that information (call it something else if you want, it doesn't have to be "flag history", I'm not picky about the name right now, just getting to what it shows) regardless of whether or not a flag had actually been cast on it.

Comment: As a slight variant of this request, I'd like a link to the normal revision history, if it has any entries, even if none of the entries is an edit. That's relevant even for non-moderators.

Answer (score 2):

This is now available from a post's **mod** menu, which contains a **show flag history** option, as well as a more general **timeline** option.

Answer (score -3):

If you want always-available links to the revision history (as well as the often-overlooked timeline, and a few other things), try installing [the SE Modifications userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a).

Comment: The script is fine (although Chrome currently makes it a PITA to install it now, I can't install it from StackApps directly, whatever) I shouldn't have to install a script to my browser to help with my moderator duties.  If you give me a link that says "this event happened" you need to give me a the ability to follow it up.  The script is a workaround which I'll use (for now), but the feature should be in there. **TL;DR** Don't make moderators have to hack things if you want them to track down a flag that Community raises.

Comment: What he wants is clearly possible; it's just adding a link to a page (even if I misunderstand which link on which page).

Comment: @casper: I have no real beef with the request, but you didn't really have to hack URLs to get this info since folks have been working around this for quite a while now. Even if the flag history *was* enabled, it still wouldn't really be obvious at first glance what was happening in this particular scenario (since... well, it had kinda stopped being a problem by the time you saw it).

Comment: @Shog9 I admit that it was Google Chrome which made me have to hack the URL (I *had* that script installed, it wen't bye-bye with the security changes, I assume).  I don't want it to be obvious (for example, I don't think a link for revisions is necessary when there is only a single revision); I simply want to get at that info from behind the scenes and we shouldn't have to work around it if we're prompted by an automated bot.  If a bot is going to say "hey, you need to check these things out", give me the ability to fully check them out without working around it.

Comment: @Shog9 I obviously don't need this *now*, but to enable that one mod ability even when there are no flags on the post would provide me with the means to research that from within the system.